window.speechSynthesis pronounce the wrong word
window.speechSynthesis pronounce lamé  /ˈlɑː.meɪ/ when I instruct it to pronounce lame  /leɪm/, why? Is there any fix for it?
const message = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    message.text = "lame";
    message.lang = "en-US";
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(message);

I test in both Chrome and Firefox on a Windows laptop, the same result. However, in Chrome on Android, it is fine. Which suggested something to do with the OS.

This happens because the lang has configured to en-US, if you try to test using the google translator, will get this same result. What is your language, this can help to locate your English lang config.

Edit: try using "lamé", will return this expected pronounce /ˈlɑː.meɪ/.


According to Cambridge, there is lame with /leɪm/ pronunciation in en-us, how can I get it from speechSynthesis?

Could you tell me your browser? I'm using firefox currently, and the pronounce seems right

I tested it with both Chrome and Firefox, the same result.
